# STR_TO_DATE in MySQL in INSERT query returns null

Tags: mysql

The following SELECT returns null.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('27/09/2016 17.51.55','%d/%m/%Y %H%i%s');
```

I tried also adding the dots between '%H%i%s', but I get the same result.

Can anyone show me what is wrong here?

Comment: With dots, this query is fine. Check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/71273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('27/09/2016 17.51.55','%d/%m/%Y %H.%i.%S');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong Format (missing the dot in time part):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('27/09/2016 17.51.55','%d/%m/%Y %H.%i.%s');
```

see the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/71273):